# Getting an error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

ERROR: Object variable or with block variable not set

CODE :

```
x.Worksheets.Add().Name = "ab"

x.Worksheets.Add().Name = "bc"

LastRow = x.Sheets("Summary").Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim pos As Range

For j = 1 To LastRow

    Set pos = x.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:X" & j).Find(What:="SAP_ALL", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    a = pos.Column

Next j
```

Error is on the line `a = pos.Column`

Answer (score 1):

If the `Find` operation didn't find anything, then `pos` will be `Nothing`.

You need a guard clause:

```
If Not pos Is Nothing Then
    a = pos.Column
End If
```

Comment: Remove all text from column A and you'll get the same error when setting `LastRow`.  I'd set up a variable to hold that reference to so you can check if it's nothing before taking the row number - if it's nothing, set LastRow =1 otherwise set it as the row from the cell reference.